# find duplicate arrays in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, geometry, aggregation-framework, gis

I have LineString geometries in a mongodb COLL but the geometries are sometimes swapped. I want to find these too. I have a solution to find duplicated documents (see code below) in the collection when they have exactly the same geometry but I also want to find cases like:

```
"geometry.coordinates" : [ [13.1, 50.1], [13.2, 50.2] ]
"geometry.coordinates" : [ [13.2, 50.2], [13.1, 50.1] ]

//This is my actual code
db.COLL.aggregate([
    { $match: {}},
    { $group: {
        _id: { geometry: "$geometry"}, 
        dups: { "$addToSet": "$_id" },
        count: { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { $match: {
        count: { "$gt": 1 }
    }}
],
    {allowDiskUse: true} 
)
```

If you know it is not possible in mongodb then please explain why not.

Comment: Have you tried [$setEquals](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/)?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough but every document in the collection has a geometry field (and that has a coordinates field). I just checked the $setEquals but that is for comparing two array within one document, not array fields of all the documents in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue with parsing arrays to sets:

```
db.COLL.aggregate([
    { $match: {}},
    { $group: {
        _id: { 
            geometry: { 
                $setUnion: ["$geometry.coordinates"] 
            }
        }, 
        dups: { "$addToSet": "$_id" },
        count: { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { $match: {
        count: { "$gt": 1 }
    }}
],
    {allowDiskUse: true} 
)
```